# Adding Month to NewDate

Tags: iphone, ipad, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nscalendar

I am new to iPhone developer,

I made a one `custom date` in that custom date i want to add `1 month` or `3 month` or `6 month` according to frequency.

i want to add month till newDate is less then today's date.

here is my code snippet,

```
 while ([today compare:temp] == NSOrderedDescending) 
    {        
        NSLog(@"inside----- today=%@,temp=%@",today,temp);

        //add to dates
        NSDateComponents *newComponents= [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];

        if([FrequencySelText isEqualToString:@"Monthly"]){

            [newComponents setMonth:1];
        }
        if([FrequencySelText isEqualToString:@"Quarterly"]){

            [newComponents setMonth:3];
        }
        if([FrequencySelText isEqualToString:@"Half - Yearly"]){

            [newComponents setMonth:6];
        }
        if([FrequencySelText isEqualToString:@"Yearly"]){

            [newComponents setMonth:12];
        }

        // get a new date by adding components
        NSDate* temp= [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingComponents:newComponents toDate:temp options:0];

        NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];

        NSString *newDate = [formatter stringFromDate:temp];
        NSLog(@"new date=%@",newDate);
}
```

**My Log shows:** `inside----- today=2012-07-11 14:41:27 +0000,temp=2012-04-12 03:00:00 +0000`

I am getting `Exc_bad_access` at this line, `NSDate* temp= [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingComponents:newComponents toDate:temp options:0];`

**Any help will bw appreciated.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Providing value to temp again then no need provide NSDate object type again. Here u already have NSDate *temp then why r u using same name again for NSDate object

```
 temp= [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingComponents:newComponents toDate:temp options:0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this one:

```
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[[NSDateComponents alloc] init] autorelease];
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar] autorelease];

[dateComponents setMonth:1]; // Sample Add   

NSDate *tempDate = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:dateComponents toDate: temp options:0];
NSString *strTempDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:tempDate];

// New Date on strTempDate
```